# Issue with automatic reload of side menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

So I have a side menu in my ionic application that is present in my templates. Here is how I have set it up in my app.js:

```
  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/rubyonic/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl',
  })

   .state('app.studies', {
    url: "/studies",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/rubyonic/studies.html",
      }
    }
  })

   .state('app.study', {
    url: "/studies/:studynodeRef",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/rubyonic/overview.html",
      }
    }
  })
```

Here is a snippet of code from my controller:

```
$scope.nodeId = $stateParams.studynodeRef;
$scope.collections = [];
$scope.studies = [];

Studies.all().then(function(data) {
                $scope.x = angular.fromJson(data.allProjects);
                $scope.studies = angular.fromJson($scope.x.list);
            });

Studies.fetchCollection($scope.nodeId).then(function(data){
              // $scope.y = angular.fromJson(data.list);
              $scope.collections = angular.fromJson(angular.fromJson(data.list)[0].collections);
              console.log($scope.collections);
              // $scope.$apply();
});
```

Studies.all() makes a call to the Studies service that makes a http call. Each study has a unique nodeRef which is passed onto Study.fetchCollection which makes another http call. Here is the Studies service:

```
.factory('Studies',function($http,$filter,$q){
  return {
    all: function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get("http://localhost/platform/loginSuccess.json").success(
            function(data){
                // angular.copy(data, studies);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }
        );
      return deferred.promise;
    },
    fetchCollection: function(collectionId) {
            var deffered = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost/platform/project/fetch.json',
                params: {
                  'nodeRef': collectionId
                }
            }).success(function(data) {
                deffered.resolve(data);
            });

            return deffered.promise;
        }
};
})
```

So I iterate through the collections in my menu.html which is displayed as a side menu in the templates:

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="collection in collections" nav-clear menu-close ng-click="go('app.studies')" class="item item-icon-left brand-base-text-color">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-paper"></i>
            {{collection.name}}
        </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

I want the menu list to automatically update the collections every time I click on a study. Not sure how to do that any help would be appreciated

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `update collections`. Why would all items in the menu list use same path with no path parameters? Also an anti pattern using `$q` within `$http` since `$http` already returns a promise. Just return `$http`

Comment: oh that's just for testing purposes app.studies is just a dummy template. All items in the collection right now point to the same template. Studies.fetchCollection fetches a collection based on a collection id which is the noderef corresponding to a specific study in studies. I want the collections aka the items in the menu to automatically reload everytime I click on a study. Does that make sense?

Comment: Still not getting it, every time controller fires it would create `collections`. I think you need to explain where the problem lies better

Comment: So $scope.nodeId = $stateParams.studynodeRef; obtains the nodeId from the url so something like app/studies/{{study.nodeRef}}. So I have a studies.html page which is a list of studies each with an unique nodeRef. Now what I want is the side menu to update with a list of collections which correspond to the respective study nodeRef which is why I make the fetchCollection:  call to obtain a list of those collections. But it just shows me the same list of collections every time and doesn't update it, even when I refresh the page.

Comment: What happens? What do you see in the console? Have you checked the network tab to see if any http requests are being made when you load the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the causes of your problem might be related to this ([from the docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)):

> In state controllers, the $stateParams object will only contain the
>   params that were registered with that state. So you will not see
>   params registered on other states, including ancestors.

So it looks like you are trying to access a parameter that you've only registered on a nested child state from it's parent state.

Try giving your 'menuContent' view its own controller where it can access the $stateParam property you need. Here's a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/1BC5xDlmL61ewoguxDtf?p=preview) that hopefully illustrates the issue:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);


app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams){
  $scope.foo = 'bar'
  $scope.stateParams = $stateParams;
});

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      template: "<div><div ui-view='menuContent'></div></div>",
      controller: 'AppCtrl',
    })

  .state('app.studies', {
    url: "/studies/:visibleParam",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "studies.html",
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
          $scope.stateParams = $stateParams
        }
      }
    }
  })

   .state('app.study', {
    url: "/study/:studynodeRef",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "study.html",
      }
    }
  })
})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  </head>

  <body>

    <ul>
  <li><a ui-sref="app.study({studynodeRef: 'bar'})">app.study({studynodeRef: 'bar'})</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="app.studies({visibleParam: 'foo'})">app.studies({visibleParam: 'foo'})</a></li>
</ul> 

    <div ui-view></div> 

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

**studies.html**

```
<h1>Studies (has own controller)</h1>
<p>$scope.stateParams => </p>
<pre>{{stateParams}}</pre>
```

**study.html**

```
<h1>Study (parent controller only)</h1>
<p>$scope.stateParams => </p>
<pre>{{stateParams}}</pre>
```

Comment: `state('app.studies', {
    url: "/studies/:visibleParam",` Studies doesn't have a param. It is simply /app/studies however, when you click on a study then a nodeRef is obtained. If you could please clarify how that will work I would really appreciate it

Comment: Update you question with what you've tried or better yet make a demo using plunkr like I did. Have you given updated your 'app.study' view definition with its own controller. What does console.log($stateParams) give from this controller when you hit the route? The demo I gave is  there to show the concept and was not meant to be ready made solution.